# How to add left join value to html table generated in ajax

Tags: ajax, pdo

I have the following script that generates a html table and allows users to update the table rows when selected with a checkbox. They can check the row than either change value or uncheck the row. The first line of script shows the table and rows when the user opens the page.

This is the part of the script that the user is seeing when opening the page. I used the cat_name from the leftjoin as value for the category and the cat_color from the left join to color the font of the tekst in the rows. And i have if statements to declare the right name behind the stored value for purpose.

```
   function fetch_data()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"select_accounts.php",
            method:"POST",
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data)
            {
                var html = '';
                for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)
                {var purpose = data[count].purpose;
    if(purpose == "BFH") purpose = "Holders";
    else if(purpose == "CAS") purpose = "Ranking";
    else if(purpose == "aa") purpose = "Admin Account";

                
                    html += '<tr >';
                    html += '<td class=\"footer\"><input type="checkbox"  id="'+data[count].id+'" data-name="'+data[count].name+'"  data-category="'+data[count].category+'"  data-door="'+data[count].door+'" data-purpose="'+data[count].purpose+'" class="check_box"  /></td>';
                    html += '<td style="color:'+data[count]['cat_color']+' " class=\"footer\">'+data[count].name+'</td>';
                   
                    
                   
                    html += '<td style="color:'+data[count]['cat_color']+' " class=\"footer\">'+data[count].cat_name+'</td>';
                    html += '<td style="color:'+data[count]['cat_color']+' " class=\"footer\">'+purpose+'</td>';
                    </tr>';
                }
                $('tbody').html(html);
            }
        });
    }

    fetch_data();
```

Now my questions. I would like to do the same to the table the user is seeing when he unchecks the checkbox. But i cant seem to get this working. Here is the part of the script the user is seeing after he unselects the checkbox;

```
html = '<td class=\"footer\"><input type="checkbox" id="'+$(this).attr('id')+'" data-name="'+$(this).data('name')+'"  data-category="'+$(this).data('category')+'" data-purpose="'+$(this).data('purpose')+'"  class="check_box" /></td>';
            html += '<td class=\"footer\">'+$(this).data('name')+'</td>';
           
            html += '<td class=\"footer\">'+$(this).data('category')+'</td>';
            html += '<td class=\"footer\">'+$(this).data('purpose')+'</td>'
            </tr>';
                       
        }
        $(this).closest('tr').html(html);
        $('#rang_'+$(this).attr('id')+'').val($(this).data('rang'));
        $('#category_'+$(this).attr('id')+'').val($(this).data('category'));
        $('#purpose_'+$(this).attr('id')+'').val($(this).data('purpose'));
     
    });
```

And this is the query to select the accounts;

```
$query = "SELECT a.*, c.cat_color, c.cat_name, c.cat_txt FROM account a LEFT JOIN categories c ON c.cat_ID = a.category 
        WHERE `betaald` = 'Yes' AND `door` = '$usernaam' 
        ";
 
 
 
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

if($statement->execute())
{
 while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
  $data[] = $row;
 }

 echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: Anyone out there that can help me? Do i need to edit my post or question?

Comment: I guess no one here can or will help me?:(